# get sum total by using foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get a total by using the `forEach` in javascript but failing somehow... It just lists the values rather than giving me the total figure

```js
const finances = [
    ["Jan", 867884],
    ["Feb", 984655],
    ["Mar", 322013],
    ["Apr", -69417],
    ["May", 310503],
];

let sum2 = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < finances.length - 1; i++) {
  let monthDiff = finances[i][1] - finances[i + 1][1];
  // console.log(monthDiff)
//   console.log(typeof(monthDiff))
  const newArray = [monthDiff];
  // console.log(newArray)
  newArray.forEach((item) => {
    sum2 += item; 
    console.log(sum2); //listing values not giving me a total why?
  });
}
```

Comment: You should understand how loops work.. I could see that you are just starting to learn the coding.. yet you can see array.reduce function

Comment: fyi, added foreach solution aswell

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop thru each array item and get the 1st index and add it with the current sum.. on first looping, zero is the current sum..

loop no. 1 - currentSum = 0, currentValue[1] = 867884

loop no. 2 - csum = 867884, cval[1] = 984655

loop no. 3 - csum = 867884 + 984655, cval[1] = 322013

...goes on until array end

```js
    const finances = [["Jan", 867884], ["Feb", 984655], ["Mar", 322013], ["Apr", -69417], ["May", 310503]];
    
    const total = finances.reduce(
        (currentSum, currentValue) => currentValue[1] + currentSum
    , 0); // initial sum is zero
    
    console.log(total)
```

Interms of foreach

```js
const finances = [["Jan", 867884], ["Feb", 984655], ["Mar", 322013], ["Apr", -69417], ["May", 310503]];
 
    let total = 0;
    finances.forEach(item => total = item[1] + total);
    console.log(total)
```

Comment: Hope it is okay I edited the answer to use code-snippets which allows us to execute code within stackoverflow & display result. I guess in one line using `.reduce()`, we can do something like this: `console.log(finances.reduce((total, [_, x]) => total+x, 0));`. Nalla code nanba. Super.

Answer (score 0):

if using a forEach is not mandatory i would switch to reduce.
reduce give you the option to keep track of the previous value as first parameter of the callback.
for more info follow the [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
// 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
const initialValue = 0;
const sumWithInitial = array1.reduce(
  (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue,
  initialValue
);

console.log(sumWithInitial);
// expected output: 10
```